# How can I use rust Try trait with Option NoneError?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I've written a custom protocol where I've defined my own struct for a frame and it parses from bytes. My function accepts a `Vec` and parses the elements accordingly. To account for invalid frames, I am returning a `Result<Frame>` and calling `.get()` on the byte array. Here's my code:

```
fn main(){
    let emptyvec = Vec::new();
    match Frame::from_bytes(emptyvec) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Received invalid frame");
        },
        Ok(frame) => {
            println!("Received valid frame");
        }
    }
}

struct Frame {
    txflag: u8, // indicates if chunked
    msgtype: u8, // a flag for message type
    sender: u8, // which node ID sent this frame?
    routeoffset: u8, // size of array of route for frame
    route: Vec<u8>, // a list of node IDs that frame should pass
    payload: Vec<u8>, // payload data
}

impl Frame {
    /// parse from raw bytes
    pub fn from_bytes(bytes: &Vec<u8>) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        let txflag = bytes.get(0)?.clone();
        let msgtype = bytes.get(1)?.clone();
        let sender = bytes.get(2)?.clone();
        let routesoffset = bytes.get(3)?.clone();
        let routes = &bytes.get(4..(4+routesoffset as usize))?;
        let (left, right) = bytes.split_at(2);
        let data = Vec::from(right);

        Ok(Frame {
            txflag,
            msgtype,
            sender,
            routeoffset: routesoffset,
            route: Vec::from(routes),
            payload: data
        })
    }
}
```

However when I try to use this pattern I get the following compilation error, and when attempting to implement the trait I get an error that the Try trait is unstable.

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::io::Error`
   --> src/stack/frame.rs:121:34
    |
121 |         let txflag = bytes.get(0)?.clone();
    |                                  ^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::option::NoneError>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
```

Not quite sure how to proceed but I'd like to use stable features to solve this. The goal here is to be able to parse bytes and handle an invalid frame as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably what you want

```rust
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

fn main() {
    let emptyvec = Vec::new();
    match Frame::from_bytes(&emptyvec) {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Received invalid frame");
        }
        Ok(frame) => {
            println!("Received valid frame");
        }
    }
}

struct Frame {
    txflag: u8,
    // indicates if chunked
    msgtype: u8,
    // a flag for message type
    sender: u8,
    // which node ID sent this frame?
    routeoffset: u8,
    // size of array of route for frame
    route: Vec<u8>,
    // a list of node IDs that frame should pass
    payload: Vec<u8>, // payload data
}

impl Frame {
    /// parse from raw bytes
    pub fn from_bytes(bytes: &Vec<u8>) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        let txflag = bytes.get(0).ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?.clone();
        let msgtype = bytes.get(1).ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?.clone();
        let sender = bytes.get(2).ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?.clone();
        let routesoffset = bytes.get(3).ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?.clone();
        let routes = bytes
            .get(4..(4 + routesoffset as usize))
            .ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?
            .clone();
        let (_, right) = bytes.split_at(2);
        let data = Vec::from(right);

        Ok(Frame {
            txflag,
            msgtype,
            sender,
            routeoffset: routesoffset,
            route: Vec::from(routes),
            payload: data,
        })
    }
}
```

Here is [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=accf88c6c413ab8a35fe38fa5ac99151)

You are trying to call `?` on `Option`. You have to convert `Option` to `Result` (If you still want to use `?`).

Comment: You don't need to do `Error::from(...)` for every error, you can use `ErrorKind::InvalidData` directly, since `?` will automatically call `.into()` on errors. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00fb25091a6a6d0669f0742ae0a81efe)

Comment: @Frxstrem good point. Also, it's important to show longer version, for someone who is still learning

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to what Đorðe Zeljić said:

As he already pointed out the result of `bytes.get(0)` is a `std::option::Option`. When you use the `?` operator on that you already left the grounds of stable Rust. This application is only supported in unstable Rust at the moment.

If you want to stay in stable Rust, it's probably best to do what Đorðe wrote. If you want to keep using the `?` operator because it produces nicer looking code, here is what's going on:

Rust has a lot of error types, each being only able to represent what they are made for. If you are using a `std::io::Result` this implicitly uses the error type `std::io::Error` which is only able to represent typical I/O errors. This type is not able to represent “there was no value when I expected one”. That's why from applying `?` to a `Option` with the `None` value, you don't get a `std::io::Error` but a different kind of error: `std::option::NoneError`.

When your Rust application grows it will happen often, that you have to return a `Result` that can contain different types of errors. In that case you normally  define your own error type (enum), that can represent different kinds of errors. Then for each error, that can be contained, you have to define the `From` trait on your own enum. This can be a lot of repeated work, so there is a macro in the [`quick-error` crate](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error), that helps with that and implements the `From` trait automatically for each error that can be contained.

To get your code compiling, you could define the following error enum, that can represent `std::io::Error` as well as `std::option::NoneError`:

```
quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum FrameError {
        IoError(err: std::io::Error) {from() cause(err)}
        MissingValue(err: std::option::NoneError) {from()}
    }
}
```

Instead of `std::io::Result<Self>` your `from_bytes` function then has to return a `std::result::Result` that uses your new error type: `Result<Self, FrameError>`.

Completely assembled that looks like this:

```
#![feature(try_trait)]

use quick_error::*;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum FrameError {
        IoError(err: std::io::Error) {from() cause(err)}
        MissingValue(err: std::option::NoneError) {from()}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let emptyvec = Vec::new();
    match Frame::from_bytes(&emptyvec) {
        Err(_e) => {
            println!("Received invalid frame");
        }
        Ok(_frame) => {
            println!("Received valid frame");
        }
    }
}

struct Frame {
    txflag: u8,       // indicates if chunked
    msgtype: u8,      // a flag for message type
    sender: u8,       // which node ID sent this frame?
    routeoffset: u8,  // size of array of route for frame
    route: Vec<u8>,   // a list of node IDs that frame should pass
    payload: Vec<u8>, // payload data
}

impl Frame {
    /// parse from raw bytes
    pub fn from_bytes(bytes: &Vec<u8>) -> Result<Self, FrameError> {
        let txflag = bytes.get(0)?.clone();
        let msgtype = bytes.get(1)?.clone();
        let sender = bytes.get(2)?.clone();
        let routesoffset = bytes.get(3)?.clone();
        let routes = bytes.get(4..(4 + routesoffset as usize))?;
        let (left, right) = bytes.split_at(2);
        let data = Vec::from(right);

        Ok(Frame {
            txflag,
            msgtype,
            sender,
            routeoffset: routesoffset,
            route: Vec::from(routes),
            payload: data,
        })
    }
}
```

To use the `quick-error` crate, you have to add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
quick-error = "1.2.3"
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed breakdown, it was helpful for me since I'm new to Rust and still learning its features.

Comment: I got a compiler error when using `#![feature(try_trait)]` I guess there's no workaround for that on stable rust?

Comment: @crockpotveggies the `#![feature(try_trait)]` is to enable the `?` operator. This is only possible in unstable or nightly as this feature is not considered stable yet. You can install stable and unstable rust at the same time using `rustup`. To switch between them you then use the additional `+stable` or `+unstable` option to all the Rust commands (`cargo`, `rustc`, …)

Comment: Strange, I checked my local `rustup` and it says I'm on stable, yet I'm able to use `?`. Any idea how that's possible?

Comment: @crockpotveggies The `?` operator in general is stable already. Only it's usage on `Option` isn't stable yet.