# Is there a method to early return if I get a `None` from a method?

Tags: rust

Is there a method to early return if I get a `None` from a method? Example:

```rust
pub async fn found_player(id: &str) -> Result<Option<Player>> {
    let player = repo // player here is Option<Player>
        .player_by_id(id)
        .await?; // I would like to use here a magic method to return here immediately if is None with `Ok(None)`
  
    if player.is_none() {
        return Ok(None);
    }

    // Do some stuff here but WITHOUT using player.unwrap(). I would like to have it already unwrapped since is not None

    Ok(Some(player))
}
```

I tried things like `Ok_or()` but I think they are now what I need. How can I do?

I don't wanna use `match` or `if else` because I need to be as less verbose I can.

Comment: I'd use `if let ... else`. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a method that would do what you want. Normally, `Some` is mapped to `Ok` and `None` to `Err`. Your case is different.

Comment: You could do `Ok(player.map(|player| { ... do stuff with player ...; player }))`.

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: @Dogbert your solution is a problem if I need to use async/await inside the closure...

Comment: What exactly does `player_by_id()` return?

Comment: I don't use Rust seriously yet but I just found [implementing Try](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2398de97e32ef2679926dd3a80a67ca8) to be interesting in its own way :) - [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050129/how-can-i-use-rust-try-trait-with-option-noneerror)

Comment: In Rust 1.65, you'll be able to use `let else` (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93628): `let Some(player) = player else { return Ok(None) };`, until then I believe `if let` and `match` are the only options.

Comment: @Dogbert you can do that on stable using the `guard` crate, which is almost the same code with a macro call around: `guard!(let Some(player) = player else { return Ok(None); });`

Comment: That aside, now that IntoFuture has stabilised maybe we'll eventually get nice sugar like `impl IntoFuture for Option<Future<...>>`, in which case you could just use an async block inside your `Option::map` then await the result, something along those lines. Currently you probably need to mess about with the `future` crate (it has an `OptionFuture` type which is a future).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest syntax available is something like:

```
let Some(player) = repo.player_by_id(id).await? else {
    return Ok(None);
};
// player is Player here
```

Prior to Rust 1.65, it had to be spelled out using a `match` or `if let`:

```
let player = match repo.player_by_id(id).await? {
    Some(player) => player,
    None => return Ok(None),
};
// player is Player here
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with this?

```
pub async fn found_player(id: &str) -> Result<Option<Player>> {
    Ok(repo // player here is Option<Player>
        .player_by_id(id)
        .await?
        .map(|p: Player| {
            // do something with p
        }))
}
```

I don't understand why you're using Result here since your code never returns the Err case.

Comment: This: a) adds nesting, b) doesn't work if "do something with p" needs to await, which is not unlikely in an async function. As for the use of Result, the code in the question can be assumed to be a minimal example, so it goes without saying that the OP's actual code does something that can return `Err`.

Comment: @user4815162342 you're perfectly right!